# Generate various beautiful color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to generate light colors in RGB format.
A human being should be able to distinguish these colors easily.
I want a solution using JavaScript.
What I did:

```
var getRandom = function(min, max) {
    return (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
};
var randomColorGenerator = function(index) { 
    var p = getRandom(0,10)/10;
    var q = getRandom(0,10)/10;
    var r = getRandom(0,10)/10;
    var max=235;
    var min= 150;
    var rgb = [Math.floor(min + p*(max-min)), Math.floor(min + q*(max-min)), Math.floor(min + r*(max-min))];
    return rgb;
}
```

As you can see that can generate colors but we are not certain to get different colors...
A solution can be:
Two colors u,v are similar when their distance d(u,v) = sqrt [ (u(r)-v(r))^2 + ... + (u(b)-v(b))^2 ] / [sqrt(3)*255] < epsilon (where epsilon is small, assume that epsilon = 0.01);
Then we can create an array and use randomColorGenerator with that rule.

But I'm here to discuss it, about an efficient algorithm.
Basically, I will use it on the chart (Chart JavaScript) to generate a readable doughnut.
I think that we can group chart elements by three elements to do it.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that the colors are fully equally distributed across possible colors? An approximately proper solution would be a lot easier to write.

Comment: What do you want to mean when you say "An approximately proper solution".

Comment: Tbh, the simplest solution is probably to just take a random value, and if it is too close, discard it and try the next, until one is found. Yes, in theory, this can take infinitely long. In reality, unless your random generator is terribad, it won't.

Comment: Is the euclidian distance a good way to know if two values are close ?

Answer (score 1):

When I have created charts, I would simply define a list of colors that I already knew looked good and distinguishable from each other, and used them in a specified order (looping back to the first if needed). I think this is the most reliable way to make sure your chart is both readable and aesthetically pleasing.

If your question was purely theoretical, I wouldn't have said anything, but since you said:

> Basically, I will use it on chart (Chart Js) to generate a readable doughnut. I think that we can group chart elements by three elements to do it.

I just wanted to offer my two cents on it; and I would have just left a comment but my Stack Overflow reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, we are here to talk and any help is good ;)

Comment: I can use that, if I know the number of elements or an idea of the max number of these elements. But, in general I don't know. What I can do is to use statistics, get an idea of that max number with a sample.

Comment: I follow that, but after a point there would be too many different colors to be useful. Here are a couple articles regarding this point: [22 Colors of Maximum Contrast](https://lifehacker.com/some-os-x-calendar-tips-1658107833/1665644975), [Visualization Types](https://visual.ly/blog/maximum-elements-for-visualization-types)